# Prometheus remote write mTLS

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, mtls

I'm trying to set up Prometheus-to-Prometheus metrics flow, I was able to do it by flag `--enable-feature=remote-write-receiver`.

However I need to have mTLS there, can someone advice a manual or post a config sample?

Appreciate you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a second config file with **experimental** options related to HTTP server, and it has options to enable TLS:

```yaml
tls_server_config:
  # Certificate and key files for server to use to authenticate to client.
  cert_file: <filename>
  key_file: <filename>

  # Server policy for client authentication. Maps to ClientAuth Policies.
  # For more detail on clientAuth options:
  # https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ClientAuthType
  #
  # NOTE: If you want to enable client authentication, you need to use
  # RequireAndVerifyClientCert. Other values are insecure.
  client_auth_type: RequireAndVerifyClientCert # default = "NoClientCert"

  # CA certificate for client certificate authentication to the server.
  client_ca_file: <filename>
```

The documentation on this file is located at the [HTTPS AND AUTHENTICATION](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/https/) article. Note that after creating this file, you have to start Prometheus with the extra option:

```
--web.config.file=/path/to/the/file.yml
```

The above is to be configured on the receiving part. The sending part needs a client TLS certificate configured in its `remote_write`:

```yaml
remote_write:
- url: https://prometheus.example.com
  tls_config:
    # https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#tls_config
    cert_file: <filename>
    key_file: <filename>
```